# jquery click not working on ipad/iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ipad

I have a drop down list of links that I am converting into select box upon page load . This is working properly on desktop/laptops however it is not working on iphone/ipad.

I am totally new to this so I don't know what may be causing the issue because code seems to work fine and triggers page load on click event. Here is the code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($)
{
$('ul.selectdropdown').each(function(){

    var select=$(document.createElement('select')).insertBefore($(this).hide());

    $('>li a', this).each(function(){

        var a=$(this).click(function(){

            if ($(this).attr('target')==='_blank'){

                window.open(this.href);

            }

            else{

                window.location.href=this.href;

            }

        }),

        option=$(document.createElement('option')).appendTo(select).val(this.href).html($(this).html()).click(function(){

                a.click();

            });

        });

    });
    });
```

Isn't click function suppose to work on all devices?

Ahmar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `touchstart`:

```
 $('ul.selectdropdown >li a').on('click touchstart',function(){

        if ($(this).attr('target')==='_blank'){

            window.open(this.href);

        }
 });
```

Comment: it doesn't work problem is this part this is where the click actually needs to fire option=$(document.createElement('option')).appendTo(select).val(this.href).html($(this).html()).click(function(){

                a.click();

Comment: any errors?? i see you have this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577190/jquery-convert-click-function-for-ipad-iphone/21577343?noredirect=1#comment32612266_21577343 not working too

Comment: It doesn't work on iphone/ipad neither does the code provided in above thread. Check for yourself.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either, and all functionality works perfectly with just click event in standard browser