# Click event on <span> or <div> tag not working safari issue

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, safari, mobile-safari

I am facing a `Click` event issue on my iPhone(7 Plus). The click method is not working on IOS devices. But working fine on IOS Chrome.

Here is the code:

```js
$('.menuOpen').on('click', function() {
  console.log('Show Menu');
  $('.menuBar').toggleClass('d-none');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">


<span class="menuOpen">Menu</span>
<ul class="d-none menuBar">
  <li>Action 1</li>
  <li>Action 2</li>
  <li>Action 3</li>
  <li>Action 4</li>
</ul>
```

I already tried these not working for me:

[On click function is not working on safari browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35646154/on-click-function-is-not-working-on-safari-browser)

[onclick() not working in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682302/onclick-not-working-in-safari)

[jquery click not working on ipad/iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555241/jquery-click-not-working-on-ipad-iphone)

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Try changing the `span` into `button`? (Although, it works on iOS 15.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this solution add `role="button"` on `<span>` and `click` event start working for IOS device:

```
<span class="menuOpen" role="button">Menu</span>
```

It can also be fixed if we replace `<span>` with `<button>`

```js
$('.menuOpen').on('click', function() {
  console.log('Show Menu');
  $('.menuBar').toggleClass('d-none');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">


<span class="menuOpen" role="button">Menu</span>
<ul class="d-none menuBar">
  <li>Action 1</li>
  <li>Action 2</li>
  <li>Action 3</li>
  <li>Action 4</li>
</ul>
```

References:

[Safari HTML Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/AccessibilityRoles.html)

[ARIA: button role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role)

Comment: Please just use a button

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I added the solution here just in case someone else faced this kind of issue in the future.

Comment: I understand, but they also should just use a button