# Span click is not working on iphone/ipad browser

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ios, responsive-design

```
$(document).on('click', '.span-btn', function(event) {
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  if(event.target.id == null || event.target.id.length < 1) return;
  console.log(event.target.id)
});
```

Click function is not working on iOS device browsers. Tried multiple approaches - touchstart, cursor: pointer and binding to the span. Currently, I have added cursor: pointer in the css for the 'span-btn' class and the above code for handling the click.

Comment: You could try to add the event to the actual `span` and not the `document`. You are adding the `cursor: pointer` to the `span` and not the `document` as well.

Comment: The attached code should be fine. Both touchstart and click can be fired on iOS device browsers. Please share more details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Click event on <span> or <div> tag not working safari issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70667742/click-event-on-span-or-div-tag-not-working-safari-issue)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `touchstart` event for iPads and iPhones.

```
const userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
event = (userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || userAgent.match(/iPhone/)) ? "touchstart" : "click";
```

and then

```
$(document).on(event, '.span-btn', (e) => {...});
```

Comment: Works well on iPhone (13 pro max, iOs 16.0.3), but on iPad it's not great (pro 3rd generation, iOs 15.7).